# React Native - Native driver animations - height

Tags: react-native

How can I change the height, width and margin in this tutorial's code using native driver?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yQK2oaIN0yA&list=PLy9JCsy2u97k6olfalMTA_XSPz4pNuT46&index=9

Answer (score 5):

You Can do it using 'react-native-reanimated'.

The animated react-native provides can use native driver only for the following:

- translations (translateX, translateY)
- rotations (rotate, rotateX, rotateY,rotateZ)
- scaling (scale, scaleX, scaleY)
- opacity (0-1)
- skewing (skew, skewX, skewY)

If you want to use the react native animations you can the height and then change it with "scaleY". That is (currently) the only way to it using the native driver with 'react-native'.